# Looping over files with same root name and in the same folder

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains hundreds of files. These files are not all independent, in the sense that the files have names like: `name1_01.csv`, `name1_02.csv`, ..., `name1_10.csv`, `name2_01.csv`, `name_2_02.csv`, etc...
So there are several root names "name1", "name2", "name3" and so on. I need to loop over the same root, so that I can merge the content of these files (so, say, merge the content of all "name1" files) then remove duplicate lines and then move on to the other root "name2" etc.
I am not sure how to do this unless I use several nested for loops. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: have a look at [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) - you could select sets of files based on `regex` patterns and then e.g. load them to a `pandas` `DataFrame` - of course depending what you want to do further with the data.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import os
path = os.path.normpath('C:\\Users\\mateo\\Documents\\files')
path_list = os.listdir(path)
main_files = {}
for file in path_list:
    name = file.split('_')[0]
    if name in main_files:
        with open(os.path.join(path, name + '.txt'), 'a+') as f:
            with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'r') as f1:
                for line in f1:
                    if line not in main_files[name]:
                        f.write(line)
                        main_files[name].add(line)

    else:
        main_files[name] = set()
        with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'r') as f:
            with open(os.path.join(path, name + '.txt'), 'w+') as f1:
                for line in f:
                    if line not in main_files[name]:
                        f1.write(line)
                        main_files[name].add(line)
```

[image]

Here you have a merge of files with removed duplicates, please notice that for this to work the folder have to contain just the files of interest and that those files should follow a convention in the naming: 'nameN_something.extension', for your case, change the extension from .txt to .csv

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import groupby
import re

def groupby_fn(filename):
    m = re.match(r'[^_]+_', filename) # match everything up until the first '_'
    return m[0]


dir = sorted(str(f) for f in Path('.').glob('*_.csv') if f.is_file())
groups = []
for k, g in groupby(dir, groupby_fn):
    groups.append(list(g)) # these are your groupings
for group in groups:
    print(group) # this is a list of files the same prefix, such as 'name1_'
```

On my directory I had files:

```
04/10/2019  06:03 PM            28,744 donors1.csv
04/12/2019  12:02 PM             9,821 donors10.csv
04/12/2019  12:15 PM            14,019 donors3.csv
04/12/2019  12:01 PM            15,581 donors5.csv
```

So, I modified the above code thus:

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import groupby
import re

def groupby_fn(filename):
    m = re.match(r'donors\d', filename) # match everything up until the first digit
    return m[0]


dir = sorted(str(f) for f in Path('.').glob('donors*.csv') if f.is_file()) # or glob('*') if you want all files
groups = []
for k, g in groupby(dir, groupby_fn):
    groups.append(list(g)) # these are your groupings
for group in groups:
    print(group) # this is a list of files the same prefix, such as 'donors1'
```

Prints:

```
['donors1.csv', 'donors10.csv']
['donors3.csv']
['donors5.csv']
```